# How does FastApi with uvicorn utilize cpu cores?

Tags: multithreading, async-await, fastapi, uvicorn

I've been struggling to grasp the concept of the mechanism of FastApi and Uvicorn, as I understand it - uvicorn utilizes threadPool in order to add parallelism to sync functions inside endpoints, via each thread in the pool is assigned as "worker"
And the number of recommended workers is 2 x num_cors + 1.

First question:
If all the endpoints uses async def - does it mean the workers arent really doing anything ?

Second question:
If uvicoen indeed uses threads, doesn't python's GIL prevents it from actually use several cores to run several threads concurrently ?
If so why is it recommended to bind the number of threads to the amount of cores?

Third question:
How is the order of execution of the tasks is determined in both cases of the sync and async endpoints ?

Thank you,

Comment: For your second question, yes despite python using Kernel level threads,  GIL limits that only one of them to run - *Except it doesn't during IO*. When python performs IO such as `time.sleep`, file writes, network etc it *Releases GIL* so other threads can run. Nearly all of webserver activites are IO-bound, hence multithreading helps. Just that it's worse than using asynchronous functions due to extra resource and overhead for threads.